# Getting IP address of a client who sent a cURL request with JSON raw POST data

Tags: php, json, curl, raw-post

I'm dealing with Flight Search API for my clients. I want to restrict some client requests from some IP Address who didn't registered with me. All the IP Addresses of my clients I will save them in a DB.

Now a user sent me a RAW HTTP POST jSON data to my server.

`How do i get the IP address of that client who sent me a RAW HTTP POST JSON Data ?`

Is it possible in cURL ? or give me some suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cURL is for sending requests, not for reading them. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3003233/255363

Comment: Hmm, Is there any other way ?

Comment: can i do it with `CURLOPT_REFERER` in `curl_setopt` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for the ip address of the requestor

This is totally unrelated from curl... so use this when curl is used and a request is done to your php where you are about to process the request done by curl

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

and also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/3003233/1868660